# Upgraded Phoenix (phoenix 1.3) using old version's generator

Tags: elixir, generator, phoenix-framework

I recently installed Phoenix to 1.3 (previously I was using 1.2). But when I run a generator like the following:

```
mix phx.gen.json Album Song songs name:string
```

it creates the files according to the previous version of Phoenix, including `changeset` and subfolders. Like if the generator itself did not upgrade. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Phoenix version in `mix.lock` is 1.3 now?

Comment: yes @Dogbert.   "phoenix": {:hex, :phoenix, "1.3.0", ...

Comment: what does `mix phx.new --version` return?

Comment: this @Cyzanfar: Phoenix v1.3.0